# Delegate with generic list signature for passing data to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I'm quite new in C#, so I'm struggling with this more than two days. I hope that some one can help me out with this one.

Below some simplified code from my application.

I want to pass a List from Form1 to Form2 using delegate and event.

How can I do this? I read tons of explanations about events and delegates, but I still can't figure it out, how this really works.

Form1:

```
public delegate List<string> ProfileImportEventHandler();
public event ProfileImportEventHandler ProfileImported;

private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // raise an event
 OnProfileImported();
}
protected virtual void OnProfileImported()
{
   if (ProfileImported != null) // check if there are subscribers
   {
            ProfileImported();
   }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form1()
    {
      // Constructor logic
      frm1.ProfileChanged += new Form1.ProfileImportEventHandler(Form1_OnProfileImported);
    }
}

List<string> Form1_OnProfileImported()
{
    // TO DO
}
```

**UPDATE**

None of the solutions worked so far. Here is what I have already tried:

**Form 2**

```
    // use generic list for profiles that will be imported from USB-Stick
    private List<string> profilePaths = new List<string>();

    public delegate void ProfileImportEventHandler(object sender, ProfileImportEventArgs e);
    public event ProfileImportEventHandler ProfileImported;

    public delegate void ImportButtonClickedEventHandler();
    public event ImportButtonClickedEventHandler ButtonImportClicked;

    public delegate void HaveDataDelegate(IList<string> data);
    public event HaveDataDelegate HaveData;
//....

    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something... 

        // raise an event
        var ea = new ProfileImportEventArgs(profilePaths);
        OnProfileImported(ea);

        OnButtonImportClicked();

        // When there is data:
        var copy = HaveData; // Use copy to avoid race conditions
        if (copy != null)
        {
            copy(profilePaths);
        }


      // close form
      this.Dispose();        
    }


    protected virtual void OnProfileImported(ProfileImportEventArgs ea)
    {
        if (ProfileImported != null) // check if there are any subscribers
        {
            ProfileImported(this, ea);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnButtonImportClicked()
    {
        if (ButtonImportClicked != null)
        {
            // fire event
            ButtonImportClicked();
        }
    }
```

**Form 1**

```
public partial class frm_1 : Form
{
// child form
frm_2 frm2;
public frm_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // do something...

        // not sure if this is correct code and the correct place for it
        frm2 = new frm_2();
        frm2.ProfileImported += new frm_2.ProfileImportEventHandler(frm2_OnProfileImported);
        //frm2.ProfileImported += frm2_OnProfileImported;

        frm2.ButtonImportClicked += new frm_2.ImportButtonClickedEventHandler(frm2_ButtonImportClicked);
        // In creation/init:
        frm2.HaveData += DataFromForm2;
    }
   void frm2_OnProfileImported(object sender, ProfileImportEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something            

    }

    void frm2_ButtonImportClicked()
    {
        // do something             
    }

    private void DataFromForm2(IList<string> data)
    {
        // Process the data from Form2.            
    }


}
```

What am I still missing? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> frm1.ProfileChanged += new Form1.ProfileImportEventHandler(Form1_OnProfileImported);
> ```

[…]

> ```
> List<string> frmLoadProfileUSB_OnProfileImported()
> ```

First those names do not match. Second, with matching signatures you do not need (since C#2 if I recall correctly) to explicitly create the delegate. Thus:

```
frm1.ProfileChanged += frmLoadProfileUSB_OnProfileImported;
```

However, I think you have the event in the wrong place. It appears it is Form2 trying to pass data to Form1. Thus the event needs to be on Form2, with a delegate that is passed the data. Thus:

#### In Form2

```
public delegate void HaveDataDelegate(IList<string> data);
public event HaveDataDelegate HaveData;

// When there is data:
var copy = HaveData; // Use copy to avoid race conditions
if (copy != null) {
  copy(data);
}
```

#### In Form1

```
// In creation/init:
Form2Instance.HaveData += DataFromForm2;


private void DataFromForm2(IList<string> data) {
  // Process the data from Form2.
}
```

Comment: Yes, mybe you're right about the place of the event. Here is what I have:

<code>
            private List<string> profilePaths = new List<string>();
            public delegate void ProfileImportEventHandler(object sender, ProfileImportEventArgs e);

            public event ProfileImportEventHandler ProfileImported;

</code>
ProfileImported is always Null and I can't figure it out why. Should I post the code snipet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do the code formatting in a comment.

Comment: @Boris: Use backticks (and get `code` formatting). but generally for something as long as that you need to expand the question, then use comments to note that change.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried that but it didn't work as well. The reason is that `HaveData` is Null. I will post an update of all of the possibilities that I have already tried.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `copy`is always `Null` because `HaveData`is always `Null`as well. I can't really figure it out, what am I doing wrong. I read tons of articles of delegates and events and still cannot make this work. Could you help me please?

Comment: @Boris At this point I would need to set up a project and see if I can re-create. I'm unlikely to have time any time soon. I would suggest you create a minimal test project with two trivial forms with a button to trigger setting data on the other form. By using the minimal approach it is much easier to understand what is going on. You can also make things easier with naming: `SourceForm` and `DestinationForm`, so button on `SourceForm` sends data to `DestinationForm` via even exposed from `DestinationForm`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use event handlers, you should follow the general pattern, defining a class that inherits EventArgs (supposing you want to involve a list in the event) in this way:

```
// Event Args
public class ProfileImportEventArgs : EventArgs {
    private IList<string> list;
    public ProfileImportEventArgs(IList<string> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public IList<string> List {
        get {
            return this.list;
        }
   }
}

// Event Handler Delegate
public delegate void ProfileImportEventHandler(object sender, ProfileImportEventArgs e);


// Form1:
public event ProfileImportEventHandler ProfileImported;
// ...    
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // raise an event
    List<string> list = new List();
    // Add something to list if needed
    var ea = new ProfileImportEventArgs(list);
    OnProfileImported(ea);
    // Use ea.list here if necessary
}
protected virtual void OnProfileImported(ProfileImportEventArgs ea)
{
   if (ProfileImported != null) { // check if there are subscribers
        ProfileImported(this, ea);
   }
}

// Form2:

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    public Form1()
    {
      // Constructor logic
      // TODO: Instantiate frm1 first.
      frm1.ProfileImported += new Form1.ProfileImportEventHandler(Form1_OnProfileImported);
    }
}

private void frmLoadProfileUSB_OnProfileImported(object sender, ProfileImportEventArgs e)
{
    // Use and/or modify e.List if needed         
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but unfortunatelly it didn't solve my problem completely. 
I'm still missing something, but really don't know what exactly is not working. 

For some reason ProfileImported is always Null.

Comment: @Boris In my code I subscribed to ProfileChanged event, it should be ProfileImported instead, I updated the answer. If you have an frm1.ProfileImported += ...., then is should not be null anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use strong coupling.
So best solution here would be to store data in database or create proxy-object (class/struct).

like:
public (static) class ProfileChangesMonitor
{
   ...your logic here
}